# Render Apostrophe of Twitter feed is not correct in IE

Tags: html, apostrophe

Check out this page using IE : http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23testvoorklant
You will find out the apostrophe is rendered as & apos ;!

If I want to use these feeds in my website, how should I handle this problem?

Regards

Comment: I replaced & apos ; with & #39! Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

The code on that page is generally broken. When [validating the page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.twitter.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3D%2523testvoorklant&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) the W3C validator finds 43 errors and 23 warnings.

A lot of the errors is because the page is typed as HTML 4.01, but it contains a lot of XHTML code. Another frequent error is that the URLs contains `&` characters that are not encoded as `&amp;`.

The error that most likely cause the problem that you see, is that the code contains the entity `&apos;`, which doesn't exist in HTML. If a browser displays that unchanged, that is perfectly normal.

If you want to clean up that data, you can just replace those with apostrophes, or `&#39;` in the cases when it needs to be encoded.

Comment: Thanx! But why all othere browsers can render it properly?

Comment: Nami: Different browsers have different strategies for how to render code that is incorrect. They generally try to make the best of the situation, but there is differences in how they interpret the invalid code, and differences in what's considered the best way to handle it.